# Large delay between requests in WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I'm building a WordPress site and i have to do some ajax requests to get the data i need.

The problem is that between the requests there's delays of about 5/4.5 seconds so the page is very slow at loading.

[image: Chrome's network log]

How could i reduce it?